# Null field for a particular date in ms access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, null

How do I query for a particular date which is null in ms access?

For example I want the fields where current month has not been entered.

I learnt that the function for current month is `Year([Field Date]) = Year(Now()) And Month([Field Date]) = Month(Now())`.

How do I get the records where this value is null?

Comment: what about for current month . Records where current month is null

Answer (score 2):

Let's say your table name is "raw" and you want to see the records with NULL dates for the column "ShipDate".

So the SQL statement will be:

```
SELECT *
FROM raw
WHERE ShipDate IS NULL;
```